# Parsing nested json to find value of an object

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to find the value of statement object in below json file.

I am trying below code but its erroring out.

```py
import cx_Oracle
import json
import pandas as pd
f = open('test.json')
records = json.load(f)
pd.json_normalize(records, record_path = [‘ddl’], meta =['op_type', 'op_ts','pos','xid'])
```

Above gives SyntaxError: `invalid character '‘' (U+2018).`

test.json is as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "op_type": "DDL", 
    "op_ts": "2023-02-16T05:30:04.000Z", 
    "pos": "G-AQAAAMQNAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAoAAA==8057790.6.13.989", 
    "xid": "0.6.13.989", 
    "ddl": {
      "object": {
        "catalog": "", 
        "schema": "TKGGU1", 
        "object": "SRCTAB2"
      }, 
      "statement": "create table srctab2"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Like already pointed out in an answer: you're using the wrong quotes around `ddl`. Besides, the value associated with `ddl` isn't a record, so `json_normalize` won't help here.

Comment: yes, now I am getting has non list value {'object': {'catalog': '', 'schema': 'TKGGU1', 'object': 'SRCTAB2'}, 'statement': 'create table srctab2'} for path ddl. Must be list or null.

Any suggestion on how to get "statement": "create table srctab2" in a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong quotes:

```
pd.json_normalize(records, record_path = [‘ddl’], ...
                                          ^   ^
                                          |   |
```

Don't use `‘` and `’` but use `'` instead.

```py
import cx_Oracle
import json
import pandas as pd

f = open('test.json')
records = json.load(f)
pd.json_normalize(records, record_path = ['ddl'], meta =['op_type', 'op_ts', 'pos', 'xid'])
```

Comment: Below code worked.

f = open('test.json')

records = json.load(f)

print(records["ddl"]['statement'])